# encoding the categorical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

cann't import LableEncoder[image].
facing problem in importing LableEncoder from sklearn while on data processing.
It simpl says that "cann't import name LableEncoder from sklearn.preprocessing

Comment: You have a typo. It's called `LabelEncoder`

Answer (score 1):

The name of the encoder is LabelEncoder not LableEncoder

Comment: oh yes, i found that thanks